# BQ Scalar subquery produced more than one element

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi When I Run SQL Query I have next issue, why?

```
SELECT 
_raw.created_at,
_raw.name,
(select item.quantity from unnest (_raw.line_items) as item) as quantity

FROM `Orders` --as tb2 --,unnest (_raw.line_items) as item

where DATE(_raw.created_at)  = "2020-04-27"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmjSh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have next issue, why?

Below subquery produces more than one element

```
select item.quantity from unnest (_raw.line_items) as item
```

this is obvious - the output here has as many elements (rows) as many items in line_items array

So, to make your query work - you can simply add ARRAY in front of it - as in below example

```
SELECT 
_raw.created_at,
_raw.name,
ARRAY(select item.quantity from unnest (_raw.line_items) as item) as quantity

FROM `Orders` --as tb2 --,unnest (_raw.line_items) as item

where DATE(_raw.created_at)  = "2020-04-27"
```

OR make sure you limit output of subquery to just one element by adding LIMIT 1 as in below example

```
SELECT 
_raw.created_at,
_raw.name,
(select item.quantity from unnest (_raw.line_items) as item LIMIT 1) as quantity

FROM `Orders` --as tb2 --,unnest (_raw.line_items) as item

where DATE(_raw.created_at)  = "2020-04-27"
```

OR ... any other ways to restrict output of that subquery to only one element - which really depends on your specific use-case and what it is that you are trying to achieve

Comment: I use ARRAY(select item.quantity from unnest (_raw.line_items) as item LIMIT 1) as quantity and have issue with quantity product https://monosnap.com/file/nN14ML95GJd8OL0gcnC60NzbxXHGqW

Comment: i am not sure what this comment is about - i just answered your question and explained why you gettting the error